# How expensive is a render call in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-io

I'm working through the railstutorial.org which suggests making partials and rendering them, splitting our `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` into 4 files (`_shim`, `_header`, `_footer` and of course `application.html.erb` itself).
I get that from a code complexity standpoint it makes sense, but how expensive is the call to 4 different files for every single website that we `get` ?
Does it get precompiled into one file ?

Comment: The assets are precompiled so it is not really expensive and has a lot of benefits from a maintainability standpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render is somehow expensive. you can test yourself. However, its not expensive to compromise your users experience, or sacrifice code readability and maintenance.

If one day you start getting performance issues, you can always use fragment cache or at least you will have a solid reason to introduce code complexity. Don't worry to much with hypothetical scenarios. It's a problem when it's problem.